# Segmentation fault: lualatex -recorder

Tags: luatex, miktex, latexmk

I installed a 64bit MikTeX on Windows 10 and trying to get my tex-files compiling again. I'm using `luatex` as compiler together with `latexmk` and a simple `latexmkrc` file.

```
$pdflatex = 'lualatex %O %S';
$pdf_mode = 1;
$postscript_mode = $dvi_mode = 0;
@default_files = ( 'myfile.tex' );
```

Calling `latexmk` from command line shows me the following output:

```
$ latexmk.exe
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 5 February 2015, version: 4.43a.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': Rules & subrules not known to be previously run:
   pdflatex
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'lualatex  -recorder  "myfile.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: (Pdf)LaTeX failed to generate the expected log file 'myfile.log'
Latexmk: Did not finish processing file 'projektskizze.tex':
   (Pdf)LaTeX failed to generate the expected log file 'myfile.log'
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
```

Then I tried the following:

```
$ lualatex -recorder myfile.tex
Segmentation fault
```

I looked at my old installation on my old PC and couldn't find any difference: Same MikTex-Version, same perl, latexmk, lualatex and so on... except the operating system. So I don't know what to do now.

Do you have any idea?

```
Miktex: 2.9.5800
perl: perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1)
latexmk: Version 4.43a
lualatex: Version beta-0.80.0 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (rev 5238)
```

Comment: I tried the same with the following `latex` sample and I got the same error. http://mally.stanford.edu/~sr/computing/latex-example.html

Comment: No problem with TeX Live on Mac OS X

Comment: There was a bug with the --recorder option, but  it has been fixed: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2424/ so check if there are updates (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation/108490#108490 before clicking on the update button). (I have a 32bit miktex here, if the bug is still present in the 64bit miktex you should report it).

Comment: Thanks you Ulrike. Well the bug seems to be fixed but there is no new version of the package in the repository. I installed my Miktex yesterday and the `miktex-luatex-bin-x64-2.9` package was packaged on 2015-12-10. And yes, I synced the package manager ;)

Comment: Any news here? Has it been resolved by updating?